# Construct class with 'const' parameters during runtime

Tags: c++, class, parameters, runtime, constants

This is probably a simple question, but I can't find a good way to solve it. I am using an API which has a class, whose constructor need **const double** as  its parameter, such as:

```cpp
MyClass(const double value);
```

The problem is that I want to construct a series of instances but the value passed can only be known during runtime.

More clearly, here is what I have done:

**.h file**

```cpp
std::vector<MyClass> my_class_vec;
std::vector<double> my_value_vec
```

During runtime, I can get the values to make **my_value_vec** assigned. I want to use these values to construct **my_class_vec**:

**.cpp file**

```cpp
for(int i = 0; i < my_value_vec.size(); i++)
  my_class_vec(my_value_vec[i]);
```

I know this is wrong, because I can't pass **double** as a **const double** parameter. And I also have some incorrect usages on instance construction, but I can't find a good way to do what I want. Does anyone have any ideas? I really appreciate for your opinions.

Comment: "*because I can't pass double as a const double parameter.*" ... why not? Or rather more to the point, that has nothing to do with why your code isn't compiling.

Comment: Thanks @Nicol Bolas !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is wrong, but for a completely different reason. For starters, but you can certainly pass a `double` as a `const double parameter`.

```
void foo(const double b)
{
}

double c;

void bar()
{
  foo(c);
}
```

This will compile with no issues, whatsoever. The only thing that `const` specifies, ***in this case***, is that the function, `foo()`, cannot modify its parameter. That's it. It bears no relevance, whatsoever, on whether the passed value is constant or mutable. The caller is free to pass either `double`, or a `const double` as a parameter. This parameter is passed by value. This means that a copy of the parameter is made, in every case, for the called function. The copy can come from a `double`, or a `const double`, it makes no difference.

Your problem is completely different. The attempt to construct the vector is fundamentally wrong.1all wrong.

```
std::vector<MyClass> my_class_vec;
std::vector<double> my_value_vec;
```

`my_class_vec` is a vector.

```
   my_class_vec(my_value_vec[i]);
```

This will not compile for the simple reason that `std::vector` does not implement `operator()`, which is being invoked here. `my_class_vec(something)` does not add anything to a vector. There's no such thing. This doesn't construct anything. This attempts to invoke `operator()`, passing a `double` as a parameter, on the object. Since a `std::vector` does not implement the `()` operator, this fails to compile.

The correct way to initialize your sample vector, using modern C++:

```
for (const auto &value:my_value_vec)
    my_class_vec.emplace_back(value);
```

This assumes that `my_class_vec` is empty. `emplace_back()` constructs a new value at the back end of the vector, passing the double `value` to the constructor. Note that this will work with or without the `const` qualifier in the range iteration.

Comment: Thank you @Sam Varshavchik , now I know I use a wrong way to construct a class vector. But my compiler shows the std::vector<MyClass> has no member named "emplace_back". Do I miss anything?

Comment: The problem is solved after I use c++11 to compile, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

> because I can't pass double as a const double parameter.

You can, of course, the problem has nothing to with it.

The problem is about `my_class_vec(my_value_vec[i]);`, if you want to add element to `my_class_vec` according to the value of `my_value_vec[i]`, you could use [`std::vector::emplace_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) (since C++11):

```
my_class_vec.emplace_back(my_value_vec[i]);
```